# Renaming an advanced voice command in OS X Yosemite dictation

Tags: macos, voice-dictation

Is there any way to rename an [advanced voice command](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203085)?

For example, I would like to rename the advanced voice command "copy that" to "copy" without having to disable the built-in advanced voice command "copy that" and creating a new voice command "copy".

[image]

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.